# relative positioning with transition effect

Tags: css, css-position, css-transitions

I have six boxes with caption. I want caption to slide in up on mouse hover event.  I am facing two problems while doing this.

1. If I use position:absolute, Figure captions would have lost their center alignment.
2. If I use position:relative, Figure captions would have became center aligned but they could not animate.

So overall I want to align Figure captions in center and it should animate from bottom to top.

I have tried following things:

```
Left: 50%;
Right: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
margin-left 50%;
```

But this will cause center alignment of the page but I want captions to be aligned canter of the box not of the page.

Here is the example

```css
a:hover img{
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
}
a:hover .caption{
 display: inline;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
 transform: translateY(-10px);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
figure{
 overflow: hidden;
}

figure img{
 height: 105px;
 width: 120px;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.caption{
 display: none;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
 transform: translateY(100%);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
 color: $fff;
}


.btn-row{
 margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.box-btn{
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #bdc1c4;
 background-color: $white;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<center><br>
 <div class="btn-row">
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">xyz</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
      <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">xyz</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">abcdefghijkl </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="btn-row">
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">short text</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
    <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">long text coming here
            </figcaption>
  </figure>
   </a>
    <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
     <figure class="box-btn">
      <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
      <figcaption class="caption">defghi</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </center>
```

Comment: I suggest visiting this site http://materializecss.com/cards.html and check the css for Card Reveal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the `display` property. Your animation is made while `display: none;`, which isn't really useful. Just remove this `display` definitions and the animation will work fine.

(I changed the color of the captions to black in the snippet to view them)

```css
a:hover img{
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-20px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-20px);
 transform: translateY(-20px);
}
a:hover .caption{
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
 transform: translateY(-10px);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
figure{
 overflow: hidden;
}

figure img{
 height: 105px;
 width: 120px;
 padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s;
}

.caption{
 font-size: 1.4em;
 color: #000;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
 -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
 transform: translateY(100%);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
 outline:none;
 color: $fff;
}


.btn-row{
 margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
 display: inline-flex;
}

.box-btn{
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 1px solid #bdc1c4;
 background-color: $white;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 outline: none;
}
```

```html
<center><br>
 <div class="btn-row">
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">xyz</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
      <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">xyz</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">abcdefghijkl </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
</div>
<div class="btn-row">
 <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">short text</figcaption>
  </figure>
 </a>
    <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
  <figure class="box-btn">
   <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
   <figcaption class="caption">long text coming here
            </figcaption>
  </figure>
   </a>
    <a href="domainSearch.html" class="link">
     <figure class="box-btn">
      <img src="style/img/university.jpg" class="img">
      <figcaption class="caption">defghi</figcaption>
     </figure>
    </a>
   </div>
  </center>
```